# Python: check if object exists in generator

Tags: python, list, range, generator

I had a bug which was caused by the changing result of checking "if x in generator"

```
def primes(upper_limit):
    for n in range(2, upper_limit):
        if all(n % i > 0 for i in range(2, n)):
            yield n

first_hundred_primes = primes(100)

print(5 in first_hundred_primes)
print(5 in first_hundred_primes)
print(5 in first_hundred_primes)
print(5 in first_hundred_primes)
print(5 in first_hundred_primes)
```

This gives the output:

```
True
False
False
False
False
```

I'm assuming one isn't meant to check if an object exists in a generator, but if this is the case why doesn't it throw some error, and why does this work?

```
>>> hundred_generator = range(1,100)
>>> 50 in hundred_generator
True
>>> 50 in hundred_generator
True
>>> 50 in hundred_generator
True
```

I usually turn the generator into a set before I'm checking if some object exists in it (to speed up checking) and this fixes the problem, but I would very much like to know what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you iterate over the elements of a generator, you *consume* them.

Try this:

```
len(list(first_hundred_primes)) > 0
=> True
len(list(first_hundred_primes)) > 0
=> False
```

I.e. you're done consuming the elements the first time you use `in` (which iterates over them), or at list all the elements up to 5, thus the generator will not generate 5 again after that. After the second time, it won't generate anything anymore.

Your options:

1. convert your generator to a list (or a set) before using it: `first_hundred_primes = list(first_hundred_primes)`
2. create a new generator each time: `5 in primes(100); 5 in primes(100); ...`
3. use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

EDIT:

As to your question about `range`: `range` isn't a generator.

In python2, it simply returns a list.  No problem there.

In python3, it returns a special object which looks like a collection.  It doesn't have to actually store all the numbers in the range, it simply implements the list-operations based on the rule defining the range. E.g. `len` is implemented as `stop-start`. Since it stands for a collection, and not a generator, you can iterate over it many time, without "consuming" the elements.

Comment: Wow, that's good to know. As for my second example, hundred_generator = range(1,100). The elements don't seem to be "consumed", the 50 in hundred_generator succeeds each time, do you have any insight as to what is going on there?